# Nginx bad gateway, how to notify

Tags: error-handling, nginx, notifications

I'm running nginx in ubuntu server, sometimes it get bad gateway error and I couldn't know it before I go to my site,

Exist a way to send me a email notification when this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only thing I can think of is to check out [Nagios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9107/what-tools-do-you-use-to-monitor-a-web-server).  Here are [installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/nagios.html) for Nagios on Ubuntu.

According to Nagios' documentation, it looks like it can send alerts if there are web server issues.

However, this is really overkill if all you want to do is monitor whether nginx is properly running or not...  I personally use [monit](http://mmonit.com/) on my Linode to monitor nginx, so that if it dies or if it runs high on memory usage, monit will automatically restart nginx.

Hope this helps!