# PHP / Magento page down module

Tags: php, magento

I want to know whenever a page is throwing an error exception (500 server error). Send an email or something.

Is there a magento module or PHP module that achieves this?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it a nonsense. 500 may mean that web server wasn't able to even execute the PHP. Or Magento itself can "crash" and in that case it won't be able to execute any plugin.

Comment: That's what i'm looking for. going for a sh script.

Comment: I see. So in that case correct your question, please. You're asking for a (PHP or) Magento module. Depending on your web server, it usually has pages which it's sending with HTTP error codes. And you can configure this pages. So you can create a script, which is executed by a web server when particular error happens. So you don't have to parse the logs.

Answer (score 1):

If server is down, your web content won't be served. This includes Magento as well since it's `php` application.

The best way would be

- check your logs
- use other monitoring tools

Related:

- [Nginx bad gateway, how to notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748450/nginx-bad-gateway-how-to-notify)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/9107/what-tools-do-you-use-to-monitor-a-web-server

Comment: Thanks! I'll write command script to check apache.log for 500 error.